# generic xslt to transform differently sized XMLs

Tags: xml, generics, xslt

Sorry i am new to XSLT and have a problem to create a very generic template to generate a result HTML. I dont know how to explain it simplier without much example code you see below:

Here is the XML with dummy-data, the important thing is that i have many tags/children like `<Test_Info>` (child of `<Dataroot>`). But they has the same structure as `<Test_Info>`. So mostly the 3rd `<Element>` contains the important results. The Problem is that from file to file i can have 3 Results (like Result3, Result4, Result6) and in another file i can have 30 of them (Result1, Result4, Result[N]...).

I hope i could explained it well to understand my problem

and sorry for my english i am not a native speeker

EDIT:
Thanks to michael.hor257k it works for this section (Test_Info) but when i add another one than it generates garbage. I expand my XML example to explain my further problem:

```
<?xml-stylesheet version='1.0' encoding='ISO 8859-1'?>
<Dataroot>
  <Test_Info>
    <Element>
        <Signal/>
        <Monitor/>
        <Data>
            <Type/>
            <Result3/>
            <Result4/>
            <Result6/>
        </Data>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Signal>Test</Signal>
        <Monitor>-</Monitor>
        <Data>
            <Type>Name</Type>
            <Result3>-</Result3>
            <Result4>-</Result4>
            <Result6>-</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>Test_Detail</Type>
            <Result3>pre</Result3>
            <Result4>pulse</Result4>
            <Result6>post</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>GlobalErr_Count</Type>
            <Result3>0</Result3>
            <Result4>6</Result4>
            <Result6>0</Result6>
        </Data>
    </Element>
  </Test_Info>
  <Test_1>
    <Element>
        <Signal/>
        <Monitor/>
        <Data>
            <Type/>
            <Result3/>
            <Result4/>
            <Result6/>
        </Data>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Signal>Systemtime</Signal>
        <Monitor/>
        <Data>
            <Type>Stamp</Type>
            <Result3>01.01.1999 14:52:00</Result3>
            <Result4>01.01.1999 14:52:50</Result4>
            <Result6>01.01.1999 14:53:26</Result6>
        </Data>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Signal>Signal1</Signal>
        <Monitor>0</Monitor>
        <Data>
            <Type>Testphase</Type>
            <Result3>pre</Result3>
            <Result4>pulse</Result4>
            <Result6>post</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>ERR_Value</Type>
            <Result3>xxx</Result3>
            <Result4>xxx</Result4>
            <Result6>xxx</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>ERR_Volt</Type>
            <Result3>yyy</Result3>
            <Result4>yyy</Result4>
            <Result6>yyy</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>ERR_Timestamp</Type>
            <Result3>65535</Result3>
            <Result4>65535</Result4>
            <Result6>65535</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>ERR_CNT</Type>
            <Result3>255</Result3>
            <Result4>255</Result4>
            <Result6>255</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>MIN_Volt</Type>
            <Result3>aaa</Result3>
            <Result4>aaa</Result4>
            <Result6>aaa</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>Max_Volt</Type>
            <Result3>zzz</Result3>
            <Result4>zzz</Result4>
            <Result6>zzz</Result6>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>MinMax_Timestamp</Type>
            <Result3>65535</Result3>
            <Result4>65535</Result4>
            <Result6>65535</Result6>
        </Data>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Signal>Signal2</Signal>
        <Monitor>1</Monitor>
        <Data>
            <Type>Testphase</Type>
            <Result4>pulse</Result4>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>ERR_Value</Type>
            <Result4>FFFF</Result4>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>ERR_Volt</Type>
            <Result4>yyy</Result4>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>ERR_Timestamp</Type>
            <Result4>65535</Result4>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>ERR_CNT</Type>
            <Result4>255</Result4>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>MIN_Volt</Type>
            <Result4>aaa</Result4>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>Max_Volt</Type>
            <Result4>ddd</Result4>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Type>MinMax_Timestamp</Type>
            <Result4>65535</Result4>
        </Data>
    </Element>
    </Test_1>
    <Test_2>
        always the same structure as <Test_Info>
    </Test_2>
    <Test_N>
        always the same structure as <Test_Info>
    </Test_N>
</Dataroot>
```

It has to be look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsDl4.png

BTW: Thanks to all, it is already better than before

Comment: You could  process `Data/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Result')]`. Does that help? Or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: you see in the XML in every `<Data>`: `<Type>` and many `<Result[N]>`, so i need a generic code for a table that contains: global column-name (Type[n]) and every row the data from the `<Result[N]>`

Comment: i have tried to put it in a table [Table_picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FGajn.png)

Comment: @WaldemarHeimann An example does not make a rule. In your current input, `Test_Info` has two `Element` nodes, while `Test_1` has four of them. We need clear and unambiguous criteria how to identify the `Element` node that has the data you want to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is have another `xsl:for-each` within the one that selects the `Element` nodes, that selects only the `Result` elements for the first `Data` element, as these correspond to the first cell on each row.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Data[1]/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Result')]">
```

Then you can get the elements that make up the row like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../../Data/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]">
```

The expression `../..` is used because you are currently positioned on a `Result` element, and you need to go back the to `Element` element to then go all the other nodes. Although be better to store a reference to the parent `Element` node in a variable.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="Test_Info">
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center"/>
            <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center"/>
            <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center"/>
            <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center">Test Detail</th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center">Global Error Count</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Dataroot/Test_Info/Element">
            <xsl:variable name="Element" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="Data[1]/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Result')]">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center"/>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$Element/Data/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]">
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you are great! works exactly like i want. maybe i have more questions about but i ask it later

Comment: ...and how can i extract the Type for the `<th>` Table-Header (..., ..., Test Detail, Global Error Count) even they are empty? Now i have to look in to XML and write them down in the xsl like: <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center"/>
            <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align:center">Test Detail</th>

Comment: See michael.hor257k's answer for an example of this. It is a separate `xsl:for-each` loop which selects the `Data` elements from the second `Element` (or perhaps the first `Element` would do, if it wasn't actually empty).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what in your example is given and what is just an example.

Assuming (among other things) that the first `Element` contains the table structure, while the second `Element` has all the data, you could something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Dataroot">
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/>
    </h3>
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="*/Element[2]/Data" />
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$data">
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="Type"/></th> 
                </xsl:for-each>       
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="*/Element[1]/Data[1]/*[not(self::Type)]">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$data">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="*[not(self::Type)][$i]"/></td> 
                    </xsl:for-each>       
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>       
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result (rendered) when applied to your example, will be:

[image]

Comment: Hello michael.hor257k, i added an edit to my question (see on top). thank you so far